# "latestSolidSubtangleMilestoneIndex" not counting up in full node

Tags: iri-node, milestones, stuck

In my full node, the *milestoneIndex* is up to date. However, the *latestSolidSubtangleMilestoneIndex* is stuck on a fix previous number. Is this correct? If not, what could be the reason for it and how to solve it?

Comment: If your neighbors are fully synced then you are probably facing one of the many instability issues of IRI :/

Comment: They are synced. So I guess that's it.

Answer (score 3):

It is a known bug in versions prior to 1.4.1.6. It's definitely not correct.

This issue is fixed in version 1.4.1.6. As stated in the release notes:
https://github.com/iotaledger/iri/releases/tag/v1.4.1.6

> - fixes stale tcp connections
> - fixes solid milestone getting stuck (regression)
> - enables checking balance based on tips
> - enables API Rate limit for new transacitons

Comment: It would be great if you can quote the relevant part of the release notes in your answer.

Answer (score 1):

This is the basic answer for IRI synchronization issues:

1. Make sure that your neighbor nodes are active and fully synchronized. If that's the case proceed with step two.
2. Restart the node **once** with the parameter `--revalidate`. It will re validate your database without removing transactions and hopefully fix the issue.